# Duda procedimiento

Tags: php, html, jquery

Buen dia, soy nuevo en PHP, y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
$mostrar = 1;
$nombre='nombre';
$tel='tel';
$msj='msj';

while ($mostrar<=$cnt){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name=<?php echo $nombre.$mostrar ?> id="nombre" autofocus="autofocus"></td>
    <td><input type="tel" class="form-control"  name=<?php echo $tel.$mostrar ?>    id="tel" maxlength="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name=<?php echo $msj.$mostrar ?>    id="msj"></td>
    <td><a href="clases/enviarws.php?nom=<?php echo $msj.$mostrar ?>"     target="_blank"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Enviar</button></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $mostrar++; }?>
  </tbody>
```

La idea es que la tabla se construye con una cantidad enviada, en un `form` previo, lo que necesito es que cuando den clic al boton de cada fila enviar el value de los input a otro archivo php.
Si me pueden ayudar!
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente meter cada fila dentro de etiquetas de fomulario, tu codigo quedaría mas o menos así:

```
<?php
$mostrar = 1;
$nombre='nombre';
$tel='tel';
$msj='msj';

while ($mostrar<=$cnt){
?>
    <form action="pagina.php" method="POST">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name=<?php echo $nombre.$mostrar ?> id="nombre" autofocus="autofocus"  ></td>
            <td><input type="tel" class="form-control"  name=<?php echo $tel.$mostrar ?>    id="tel" maxlength="10"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name=<?php echo $msj.$mostrar ?>    id="msj"></td>
            <td><a href= "clases/enviarws.php?nom=<?php echo $msj.$mostrar ?>"     target="_blank"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Enviar</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <?php $mostrar++; }?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Gracias, le añadi el target="_blank" y quedo como lo necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Si tengo bien entendido, lo que quieres hacer es que el valor de un campo se envíe a otra página. La solución a tu pregunta podría ser utilizar utilizar el atributo `action` con el valor de la página a la que quieres enviar los datos del elemento `form`.

Dentro de esa página declararías una variable `foo` con el valor de la variable global `$_POST` con el nombre que hayas indicado inicialmente en el atributo `name` del elemento `input` de la página inicial.

Finalmente llamas la variable con `echo`.

Inicialmente, tenemos el archivo **index.php**:

```html
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
  <input name="bar" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Finalmente, nuestro **foo.php**:

```
<?php
  $baz = $_POST['bar'];
  echo $baz;
?>
```

El script PHP se ejecutará en la página deseada, **foo.php**, y no en **index.php**.